# select children with id starting with a variable string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I expand:
`.children('[id^="_foo"]')` into :

```
var blah = 'abc'; // 'abc' is passed dynamically and could be other string
.children('[id^=" (blah) _foo"]')
```

so in this case the result would be: `children` with `id` starting with `abc_foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close, and you can simply use string concatenation to achieve what you want:

```
var blah = 'abc'; // 'abc' is passed dynamically and could be other string
$(selector).children('[id^="' + blah + '_foo"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just build the string including the variable `blah`:

```
var blah = 'abc';
$('selector').children('[id^="' + blah + '_foo"]');
```

Comment: @user3024007: Just be careful when mixing single and double quotes -- sometimes it can look strange and lead to one or the other being out of place.

Comment: it might've been that